# html output update on form submit

Tags: javascript, html, forms

This should be a really simple one, but I can't seem to find a solution to this anywhere explicitly. I'm looking to do a javascript calculation (from a bunch of inputs in a form), for which I get two numbers. These numbers will then update the values of two html output elements within the same form. Here's a minimal working example of what I'm trying to do (if there is a better way of doing this I'm all ears):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "~//IETF//DTD HTML//EN">
<html>
<head>
<script>
function somecalc() {
    var a = parseFloat(document.forms["form1"]["id1"].value);
    var b = parseFloat(document.forms["form1"]["id2"].value);
    var c = parseFloat(document.forms["form1"]["id3"].value);
    var d = parseFloat(document.forms["form1"]["id4"].value);
    var out1 = a-b-c-d;
    var out2 = a+b+c+d;
    var outarr = [];
    outarr.push(out1);
    outarr.push(out2);
    return outarr;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>

  <form name="form1">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Head1
        </td>
        <td>
          Head2
        </td>
        <td>
          Head3
        </td>
        <td>
          Head4
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="1" placeholder="Enter 1" id="id1" size="10" maxlength="10" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="2" placeholder="Enter 2" id="id2" size="10" maxlength="10" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="3" placeholder="Enter 3" id="id3" size="10" maxlength="10" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="4" placeholder="Enter 4" id="id4" size="10" maxlength="10"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Run" onclick="somecalc();"></p>
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <td>
          Out1 = <output name="out1" for=""></output>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Out2 =<output name="out2" for=""></output>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>

</body>
</html>
```

How could I get the first element of `outarr` to fill in out1, and likewise, the second element of `outarr` to update out2 when the Run button is pressed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just set the value of `out1` and `out2` via the value property.

```js
function somecalc() {
    var a = parseFloat(document.forms["form1"]["id1"].value);
    var b = parseFloat(document.forms["form1"]["id2"].value);
    var c = parseFloat(document.forms["form1"]["id3"].value);
    var d = parseFloat(document.forms["form1"]["id4"].value);
    var out1 = a-b-c-d;
    var out2 = a+b+c+d;
    document.forms["form1"]["out1"].value = out1;
    document.forms["form1"]["out2"].value = out2;
    return [out1, out2];
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "~//IETF//DTD HTML//EN">
<html>
<body>
  <form name="form1">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Head1</td><td>Head2</td><td>Head3</td><td>Head4</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="1" placeholder="Enter 1" id="id1" size="10" maxlength="10" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="2" placeholder="Enter 2" id="id2" size="10" maxlength="10" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="3" placeholder="Enter 3" id="id3" size="10" maxlength="10" />
        </td>
        <td>
          <input type="text" name="4" placeholder="Enter 4" id="id4" size="10" maxlength="10"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Run" onclick="somecalc();"></p>
    <table border="1">
      <tr>
        <td>
          Out1 = <output name="out1" for=""></output>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Out2 =<output name="out2" for=""></output>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Excellent - this works. I've accepted this answer because it was first, and I have to modify my code the least :)

Answer (score 1):

```
function somecalc() {
    var a, b, c, d, out1, out2;
    a= parseFloat(document.forms["form1"]["id1"].value);
    b = parseFloat(document.forms["form1"]["id2"].value);
    c = parseFloat(document.forms["form1"]["id3"].value);
    d = parseFloat(document.forms["form1"]["id4"].value);
    out1 = a-b-c-d;
    out2 = a+b+c+d;
    document.querySelector("output[name=out1]").innerHTML = out1
    document.querySelector("output[name=out2]").innerHTML = out2
}
```

Try this or you can 'id' s in your html like

`<output id="out1" .. >`
and `document.getElementById("out1").innerHTML = out1`

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this also. You could use `document.querySelector` or the method you use instead of `document.getElementById` I just did that for simplicities sake when trying to work through your code.

Generally javascript files are linked to external files instead of being declared in a script tag, but I suppose you could be doing this for homework or something where putting it all in the HTML makes it a little simpler. If you did seperate it out you would have to make a click handler such as in my code which is the `btnRun.addEventListener('click', runClick);` Also the `e.preventDefault()` prevents the default action of the submit button which is submitting the form via whatever action is stated (GET, POST, etc..)

Also Mozilla Developer Network has great resources for javascript syntax and examples if you don't know about it https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript

```
var btnRun = document.getElementById('run');

var out2 = document.getElementById('out2');
var out1 = document.getElementById('out1');

function runClick(e){
  e.preventDefault();   

  var output1, output2;
  var a = parseFloat(document.getElementById('id1').value);
  var b = parseFloat(document.getElementById('id2').value);
  var c = parseFloat(document.getElementById('id3').value);
  var d = parseFloat(document.getElementById('id4').value);


  output1 = a + b + c + d;
  output2= a - b - c - d;
  out1.innerText= output1;
  out2.innerHTML = output2;
}

btnRun.addEventListener('click',  runClick);
```

Comment: Forgot to mention used both innerText and innerHTML to change the output boxes just for reference of different ways you could do this based on your needs.

Comment: Okay, this seems like something I might want to do actually. The minimal working example is actually an abbreviated version of my full code, for which I do load in my functions externally. Right now, the above solution is working, though when I try to implement this in the larger site (I suspect due to css/javascript of the template I'm using), it actually isn't working well. What I mean by this is after run is clicked, the calculation is performed, but then  it quickly erases all input/output in the form I was just filling out, and jumps to the top of the page; this is very bad.

Comment: Would you be willing to check things out and perhaps comment on what might be going wrong? I've tried your solution, but I don't think it's fixing my problem. For example, see the form at the bottom of this page: http://www.physics.drexel.edu/~groenera/massconvert/index.html

Comment: I'll give it a look. I'm guessing it's because your event for the click on the run button is still attached to the html as onclick() . If you took that out and made an event listener such as the btnRun listener in my example you could pass the event object into the runClick function and use e.preventDefault() which stops the default action of the click and does what you tell it to do in the function